# How to enable Identity Insert for multiple tables at once?

Tags: sql-server, data-import

I'm using the SQL Server 2014 Import and Export Wizard to copy data from one SQL Server instance to another.

I have 8 databases, each with 63 tables, so 504 tables in total.

The Import/Export works just fine, data flows across into the destination database. The issue I have is that I need the `Enable Identity Insert` option for every table.

I need `Enable Identity Insert` defaulted to ticked/selected, otherwise I'm going to be here all day just clicking `Edit mappings... > Enable Identity Insert > OK`... Move down... `Edit mappings... > Enable Identity Insert > OK`... Move down... `Edit mappings... > Enable Identity Insert > OK`...

You get the idea...

Is there any way to set the default for `Enable Identity Insert`..?

Comment: Can only be set for one table at a time. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql  `At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON. If a table already has this property set to ON, and a SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON statement is issued for another table, SQL Server returns an error message that states SET IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON and reports the table it is set ON for.` With 504 tables you might be better off doing something dynamic or using SSIS with a loop.

Comment: Why do you need it on on every table? If you always need to insert the value of the identity, then it sounds like having it as an `INDENTITY` column is the wrong choice; it's designed more for when SQL Server will handle the creation of the ID, not the user. Perhaps the problem isn't needing to switch `INDENTITY_INSERT` on, but that you've used an `IDENTITY` column, and need to change it to simply be an `int`/`bigint`.

Comment: Maybe replication would be a better option for copying the data?

Comment: @JacobH That's not the problem. I'm not working in SQL directly, I'm using the Import/Export wizard that comes with the Management Studio. Ticking the `Enable Identity Insert` for all tables works. My question is about defaulting that tick box to ticked/on - so I don't have to tick it manually 504 times.

Comment: @Larnu All 63 tables have a Primary Key `Int` ID column, most set to auto increment. I'm copying all the data, from all the tables, from one SQL instance to an identical instance (same table names and structure). That's how this database is setup, I'm not about to make major changes to accommodate this one-off data move. My question is about defaulting the tick box to ticked in the export/import wizard, not my use of ID columns.

Comment: I don't think you *can* change the default values on the Import/Export wizard. It's not, really, the greatest tool in the world, in all honesty; it's very much a "that'll do" application. It's not a replacement for a proper ETL process, such as using SSIS.

Comment: @Larnu You can do it, I've added an answer... You are of course right, the import/export wizard is a basic tool. This is a one-off data transfer so it works for me this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found this which answers my question:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190119/how-to-set-enable-identity-insert-for-all-the-tables-at-once-during-importing

You can do it...

You select multiple rows, then the `Edit mappings...` button leads to a different dialog box, where you can set options for all tables. The answer above has a nice print-screen showing this.

Sounds simple, but I think I missed it because the interface has two selection methods on one form:

1. Tick box selection - for including the source table in the data transfer
2. Highlight row selection - for selecting multiple rows to set options